# Check if is an Object

Tags: javascript

I need to check if a variable is a pure Object instance. For example: a HTMLElement is *instanceof* Object. But I really need to check if it is *only* an Object, like `{a: true, b: false}` is. It not can validate an Array.

***Note**: I can use newer features of Chrome, if better.*

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Are you really trying to see if an object is a host or native object? An HTMLElement is not necessarily an instance of the built–in Object object. Elements are host objects and therefore do not need to follow any particular inheritance pattern (and some browsers do not implement any, nor do they implement them as instances of Object).

Comment: look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/ in the source of jquery http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.jsand then close this question until you are blind

Comment: If it only needs to work in a very limited set of browsers,  does checking that `object.__proto__ === Object.prototype`. But that is absolutely not recommended for the general web.

Comment: @AndyRay—the jQuery method is pretty awful, and contains this gem: `Own properties are enumerated firstly`, which not only has no basis in any relevant standard, it's demonstrably wrong in practice. Probably the only reason it doesn't cause an error is that the following line is never (or very rarely) reached.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check the constructor. [Seems to work in all browsers](http://jsfiddle.net/zEWYY/)

```
if (a.constructor === Object)
// Good for arrays
([]).constructor === Object => false
// Good for HTMLElements
document.body.constructor === Object => false
```

Comment: Thanks for all replies... But this is perfect and speedy for me. Thanks you!

Comment: The constructor property can be set, so easily spoofed: `var a = []; a.constructor = Object; o.constructor === Object; // true`

Comment: @RobG Sure, there are many things you can do to shoot yourself in the foot with JS. You can also spoof `object.__proto__` which you have suggested, but I suppose that would actually make something an Object???

Comment: @RobG: Probably a better example is the fairly common practice of replacing the prototype object of a custom constructor, like: `MyCtor.prototype = {myMethod: function() {}, ...}`

Comment: @JuanMendes—just pointing it out so the OP (and others) can make an informed decision. Javascript's loose typing is one of the things that people coming from other languages find difficult to come to terms with. "When is an object an Object" is a conundrum that is best avoided as there is no simple answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);

var protoproto = Object.getPrototypeOf(proto);

if (proto === Object.prototype && protoproto === null) {
    //plain object
}
```

If you'll be creating objects with a `null` prototype, you could get rid of the `protoproto`, and just compare `proto` to `Object.prototype` or `null`.

The danger of that is that it doesn't guard against being passed `Object.prototype` itself, perhaps causing accidental extensions of `Object.prototype`.

---

A little shorter and safer like this:

```
var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);

if (proto && Object.getPrototypeOf(proto) === null) {
    // plain object
}
```

---

Comment: *sidenote:* min browser version requirements: Firefox 3.5, Chrome 5, IE 9. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf